# How to configure DNS server to share the service between two differnet domains

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, configuration

I have encoutered a problem on a network integration.

### Systems

There are 2 domains on the same level: `domain1.local` and `domain2.local`.
Each domains is managed by a Win Server 2003 `server1 (192.168.225.42)` and `server2 (192.168.220.16)` (DNS server and Domain Controller).
Each domain is declared as a stub domain on each other.
Alias have been added to resolve `serverone` as `serverone.domain1.local` on `server2` and `servertwo` as `servertwo.domain.loc` on `server1`.

1. on server1

   > > C:>ping server1
   > >     Pinging server1 [192.168.225.42] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.42.16: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
   > >
   > > C:>ping server1.domain1.local
   > >     Pinging server1.domain1.local [192.168.225.42] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.42.16: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
   > >
   > > C:>ping servertwo
   > >     Pinging servertwo.domain2.local [192.168.220.16] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.42.16: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
   > >
   > > C:>ping servertwo.domain2.local
   > >     Pinging servertwo.domain2.local [192.168.220.16] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.42.16: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
2. on server2

   > > C:>ping server2
   > >     Pinging server2 [192.168.220.16] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.220.16: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
   > >
   > > C:>ping server2.domain2.local
   > >     Pinging server2.domain2.local [192.168.220.16] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.220.16: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
   > >
   > > C:>ping serverone
   > >     Pinging serverone.domain1.local [192.168.225.42] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.225.42: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
   > >
   > > C:>ping serverone.domain1.local
   > >     Pinging servertwo.domain2.local [192.168.225.42] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.225.42: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

### Problem

Domains can't resolve the `server1` and `server2`.

1. on server1

   > > C:>ping server2
   > >     Ping request could not find host dc-server.localdomain.org. Please check the name
   > >     and try again.
   > >
   > > C:>ping server2.domain2.local
   > >     Pinging server2.domain2.local [192.168.220.16] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.220.16: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
2. on server2

   > > C:>ping server1
   > >     Ping request could not find host dc-server.localdomain.org. Please check the name
   > >     and try again.
   > >
   > > C:>ping server1.domain1.local
   > >     Pinging server1.domain1.local [192.168.225.42] with 32 bytes of data:
   > >     Reply from 192.168.225.42: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

### Question

Actually I I can work around this by adding a host file entry mapping `server1` and `server2`.
But how can I use DNS configuration to avoid this hack ?
I've tried to create Aliases without success...

Answer (score 4):

On server1 go to `Network Connections -> Local Area Connection N -> Properties -> TCP/IP -> Properties -> General -> Advanced -> DNS tab`. Here make sure you have selected `Append these DNS suffixes (in order)` and put into the list:

```
domain1.local.
domain2.local.
```

Ping, like most programs, uses a built-in DNS resolver. If you give it any name, for example `thatserver`, it firstly tries to query DNS server for `thatserver.`. If the DNS replies  "not found", it tries to append suffixes. In this case, it would search for  `thatserver.domain1.local.` and if "not found", then for `thatserver.domain2.local.`. If the domain is not in the list, it will not search it - disregarding the fact that the domain is defined on a 127.0.0.1 DNS server.

Vice versa on server2 (same thing, but the order of the domains in the list reversed).

Comment: Is that the point at the end is voluntary?

Comment: No, the ending point "." is very important. This means root of the tree. Dot indicates that the name is absolute. For example google.com. is always the site you expect, but google.com without ending dot could possibly be resolved to google.com.domain1.local. This is like the difference between "C:\Windows\system32" and "Windows\system32".